# Ambuiguity in C using Printf

Tags: c

Why does C language acts like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
 const int size = 3;
 double a[size];
 for(int n=0; n<size; ++n){
   a[n] = n;
   printf("%d,%d\n",n,n+1);
 }
}
```

Output is

```
0,1 
1,2 
2,3
```

But When i do this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main()
{
 const int size = 3;
 double a[size];
 for(int n=0; n<size; ++n){
   a[n] = n;
   printf("%d,%d\n",a[n],n+1); //change is here
 }
}
```

Output is :

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
```

Why does the value changes just by replacing `n` and `a[n]` which are same?

Answer (score 6):

`a[n]` is a double, which you can’t printf with %d

Comment: Technically, one *can* print a `double` with `%d`, but the behavior is undefined per standard. An implementation would need to specify this behavior. But I'm not aware of any implementation which does that.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Technically, one can **try** to print a double with %d

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's wanted I wanted to say, too. The one *can* or *try* whatever s/he likes, but it the behavior is not defined. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to the fact in the second you are trying to print `a[n]` which is a `double` using `%d` format specification, which is for `int`, resulting in undefined behavior.

For example, in my system I get this printed:

```
1,1559556488
2,1559554816
3,1559554816
```

The compile should be warning you about this.
C-lang gives you one:

```
clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:9:21: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'double' [-Wformat]
   printf("%d,%d\n",a[n],n+1); //change is here
           ~~       ^~~~
           %f
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

> "*Why does the value changes just by replacing `n` and `a[n]` which are same*"

When you using `printf("%d,%d\n", a[n], n+1);` in the second example, the second argument (`a[n]`) is of type `double`, whereas in the first example `n` is of type `int`.

That you use `n` of type `int` as index doesn't make the addressed `double` object of type `int`.

---

To use the `%d` conversion specifier to print a `double` value invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

The C standard states:

> d,i **The `int` argument** is converted to signed decimal in the style[-]dddd.   The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/8

and

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.288) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.
>
> Source: C18, 7.21.6.1/9